# Botan::DSA_PrivateKey to DSA_PublicKey how to?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans-8, dsa, botan

I've succeeded with creating a new `DSA_PrivateKey` and `Botan::PKCS8::PEM_encode` to save to a `.pem` file. Now I need to save the PublicKey to a separate `.pem` also. Anybody know how to copy the `DSA_PrivateKey` to a `DSA_PublicKey`? I tried many different things none worked.. Shall appreciate this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, use:

```
Botan::DSA_PublicKey(DL_Group, privatekey->get_y());
```

then

```
keystring = Botan::X509::PEM_encode(pubkey);
```